# XNA: make a sound instance play just once upon activation

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I am making a game in XNA and when the player levels up I have a sound playing. The sound plays over and over, it isn't set to loop and setting .islooped to false doesn't stop it.

Is there any simple command to make it just play once?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using so far? It would help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the SoundEffect class given in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio library.

The sound effect content is loaded just like any other content in xna using Content.Load method. The SoundEffect class contains a method Play(), which will play your sound only once. If you are using SoundEffects then be sure to check if there are any unwanted loops happening when playing that sound.